# More efficient method to compute moments of the Johnson $S_B$ distribution

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, probability-or-statistics, distributions

Here is a very specific feature request. I need

```
Mean[JohnsonDistribution["SB", γ, δ, 0, 1]]
```

When I issue e.g.

```
Table[N[Mean[JohnsonDistribution["SB", γ, δ, 0, 1]]],
      {γ, -10, 10}, {δ, 1, 10}] // TableForm
```

I get several messages of the form

```
NIntegrate::ncvb: "NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after
9 recursive bisections in Statistics`DistributionPropertiesDump`x$10142 near
{Statistics`DistributionPropertiesDump`x$10142} = {1.}. NIntegrate obtained
0.9960487815187503` and 0.03645902871201284` for the integral and error estimates."
```

which seemingly indicates that *Mathematica* tries to find the mean using numerical integration.

I could live with this somehow, but actually, I also need several higher moments of that distribution (because I want to estimate a distribution with them as the Maximum Likelihood method seems to be too sensitive to fluctuations in my empirical data). And with higher moments, this seems to be even worse - when I am trying to compute an estimated distribution with the method of moments, *Mathematica* goes on computing for a long time and I stopped it, since I need very many instances of it, and it would be impractical.

So much for the motivation. Now here's what I've been able to find out about this:

In the Appendix to the [initial paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/biomet/36.1-2.149) where Johnson introduced his distributions, he gives a series expansion for the mean of his $S_B$ distribution based on papers of Mordell in [1920](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/showciting;jsessionid=E823723D5010E9176136D446A0963389?cid=32374630) and [1933](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02547795) (I could not find any online file for the older one). Johnson also gives expressions of higher moments in terms of derivatives of the mean with respect to one of the parameters, and provides sort of an algorithm to compute them. His formula for the mean reads
$$\sqrt{2\pi}\delta e^{-\frac{\gamma^2}2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{\pi i\psi t^2-2\pi\nu t}}{1+e^{2\pi t}}dt$$
where $\psi=2\pi i\delta^2$ and $\nu=-\gamma\delta$.

I cannot judge how efficient his procedures might be, but what I know is that in recent years, there has been an explosion of interest in Mordell integrals from the side of number theorists, and they produced lots of new information about it.

In particular, for example, in Theorem 2.1 [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~rhoades/FILES/mordell_quantum.pdf) one may find the following:
$$\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{\pi i\tau w^2-2\pi zw}}{\cosh(\pi w)}dw=\eta(z,\tau)+e^{\frac{\pi i z^2}\tau}\sqrt{\frac i\tau}\eta(\frac z\tau,-\frac1\tau)$$
where
$$\eta(z,\tau)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-4}n\right)e^{-\pi inz}e^{-\frac{\pi in^2\tau}4},$$
with $\left(\frac{-4}n\right)$ the Jacobi symbol.

The latter series has very good convergence properties; at least, I am sure it will give a much more efficient method to handle the moments of the Johnson $S_B$ distribution than the numerical integration which *Mathematica* seemingly uses now.

Will it be possible to incorporate this?

Comment: FWIW: `Mean[]` and `Expectation[]`/`NExpectation[]` don't work, but the explicit integral works nicely with an appropriate choice of method: `Table[(δ/Sqrt[2 π]) NIntegrate[Exp[-(γ + δ Log[x/(1 - x)])^2/2]/(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}, Method -> "DoubleExponential"], {γ, -10, 10}, {δ, 1, 10}]`.

Comment: Oh, one other thing: the first term of your last sum will be problematic, considering your summation limits.

Comment: @J.M. Wow this works very efficiently, also with all higher moments (multiplying integrand by $x^k$)! Still, it would be good to incorporate this somehow, I believe an average user would hardly come up with this. Could you please make this an answer?

Comment: @J.M. As for the sum term - $\left(\frac{-4}n\right)$ is actually the Jacobi symbol rather than fraction, it is true that it must be properly interpreted for $n=0$ but in any case it should create no problems.

Comment: Ah, then you should have noted that earlier. :) (I suppose that's one annoyance of the Jacobi-Kronecker symbol...)

Comment: @J.M. Did it. And thanks for the edits.

Comment: As you have noted, the moments of the Johnson $S_B$ system are extremely complicated. As such, the method of moments is not generally used for fitting $S_B$ systems. Instead, a method of percentile points is usually used, which equates percentile points of the observed and fitted curves. The latter is not an exact methodology. I have come across some new alternative fitting methods in recent years. One can also always use Pearson fitting functions as a substitute, which is inevitably a much simpler strategy.

Comment: @wolfies Thanks for pointing this out! Could you please provide your favorite reference for Pearson fitting functions? Google throws very diverse links, I am not sure which one to follow...

Comment: @wolfies, extremely complicated indeed; I encountered special functions I haven't seen in a while in the papers the OP linked to.

Comment: `Could you please provide your favorite reference for Pearson fitting functions? ` .... Recent versions of Mma have some in-built Pearson functions. Chapter 5 of our book has extensive coverage of doing Pearson fitting w ... you can download a free copy of the chapter here:  http://www.mathstatica.com/book/bookcontents.html

Comment: @wolfies WOW thanks a lot!

Comment: @J.M. As I mentioned Mordell integrals seem to be in the spotlight now, so efficient ways to compute them are desired by many I believe

Comment: For your perusal, [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2333751) is Egon Pearson's original paper.

Comment: Actually, I'm sufficiently intrigued; if I find spare time, I'll see if I can implement the Mordell integral myself; at least, as a proof of concept; at most, an alternative strategy.

Comment: @J.M. Many thanks for the paper, and please let me know if anything comes out. I am also interested in these integrals not only because of this particular problem.

Comment: @wolfies ...and on the afterthought, concerning percentile points - haven't tried it yet but I think this will be even more sensitive to data fluctuations than ML, which was the very reason I decided to try something else.

Comment: Have you already seen [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2346692)?

Comment: @J.M. No I've never seen this. You really rock, how did you find it!?

Comment: On a hunch, I decided to look up the AS archives. **That** was a surprise to me as well.

Comment: Did you see my most recent addition?

Comment: @J.M. Oh yes, I am using it. Not only is it incredibly quick, it also covers much more cases than the previous. Only very small $\delta$s still make trouble

Comment: Hah, I think most methods for this distribution will choke in that case anyway! Oh well, them's the breaks…

Comment: @J.M. There must be quite deep reasons behind this. Mordell integrals occur as modularity obstructions, for functions having the real line as the analyticity boundary and this seems to influence its behavior near $\delta=0$ somehow

Comment: @J.M. (in other words, if one would use the approach proposed in the question, such behavior would be perfectly understandable: the function I denoted by $\eta$ there has singularities densely packed along the real line wrt second argument ($\tau$))

Comment: Not unlike the Klein invariant as a function of the period ratio, yes. Any evaluation near the "wall" runs into numerical difficulties, and necessitates a number of tricks…

Comment: @J.M. Yes exactly, except that this $\eta$ is not fully modular (if it would be, the Mordell integral would be zero!). I'm especially interested in this phenomenon because of another question [on mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/146139/41291) - see [my own (incomplete) answer there](http://mathoverflow.net/a/159219/41291).

Comment: Btw this reminds me - although it can hardly give any computational advantage, but still - there seems to be a simple linear substitution which turns the integrand into an even function of the argument, so that one might replace $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ with $2\int_0^\infty$

Comment: Normally this "fold over" accrues computational advantages; here, having the integral go over the entire real line makes the trapezoidal rule shine, so I eschew the folding here. (The double exponential substitution also proceeds on the approach of turning an arbitrary integral into a doubly infinite one, with rapid decay at both ends.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a real value with desired precision for the last parameter:

```
mom[k_Integer] := Outer[Moment[JohnsonDistribution["SB", ##, 0, 
  SetPrecision[1., 20]], k] &, Range[-10, 10], Range[1, 10]]
mom[1] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my so all I had to do is increase precision!

Answer (score 22):

I'll preface this answer first with a complaint:

> `NExpectation[]` and `NProbability[]` are not <strike>sufficiently resilient</strike> obviously adjustable.

Ideally, these two functions are an "interface" to `NIntegrate[]`, allowing the user to formulate his expression purely in distributional terms. Unfortunately, when one hits cases like this, the things one might usually fiddle with in `NIntegrate[]` **seem to be absent in `NExpectation[]` and `NProbability[]`**!

```
Options[NExpectation]
   {AccuracyGoal -> ∞, Compiled -> Automatic, Method -> Automatic,
    PrecisionGoal -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision}

Options[NIntegrate]
   {AccuracyGoal -> ∞, Compiled -> Automatic, EvaluationMonitor -> None,
    Exclusions -> None, MaxPoints -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> Automatic,
    Method -> Automatic, MinRecursion -> 0, PrecisionGoal -> Automatic,
    WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision}
```

See the difference? If something breaks while evaluating `NExpectation[]` or `NProbability[]`, a number of the things that otherwise can be adjusted in `NIntegrate[]` aren't there. This forces the user to fall back on `NIntegrate[]`, and ruefully wonder why he even thought of trying the fancy syntactic sugar in the first place.

**(But, see the addenda below.)**

---

Having said all this, the $S_B$ distribution is apparently one of those distributions that require the use of `NIntegrate[]` proper. To help us along, we display the corresponding probability density function:

```
PDF[JohnsonDistribution["SB", γ, δ, 0, 1], x]
   Piecewise[{{δ/(E^((γ + δ Log[x/(1 - x)])^2/2) Sqrt[2 π] (1 - x) x), 0 < x < 1}}, 0]
```

Thus, to assemble the $k$-th moment, we multiply this expression with $x^k$. The logistic function and the denominator present in the PDF will give the default quadrature method a spot of trouble, so we switch to a method that is relatively robust towards endpoint singularities: the *double exponential quadrature* of Takahashi and Mori:

```
SetAttributes[sbMoment, Listable];
sbMoment[k_Integer?NonNegative, γ_?NumericQ, δ_?NumericQ, opts___] := 
         Module[{prec = Precision[{γ, δ}]},
                If[prec === ∞, prec = MachinePrecision];
                (δ/Sqrt[2 π]) NIntegrate[x^(k - 1)
                   Exp[-(γ + δ Log[x/(1 - x)])^2/2]/(1 - x), {x, 0, 1},
                   Method -> "DoubleExponential", opts, WorkingPrecision -> prec]]
```

Examples:

```
sbMoment[Range[0, 5], -10, 1]
   {0.999999999999918, 0.999925163391599, 0.999850341996451,
    0.9997755358060877, 0.9997007448121356, 0.9996259690062346}

sbMoment[Range[0, 2], -5, 3, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
   {1.0000000000000000000, 0.83615201160671172434, 0.70122109224906876673}
```

---

### Addendum

As ilian notes in [his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97759), it's actually possible to pass `NIntegrate[]`'s options to `NExpectation[]`; nevertheless, the syntax is not as transparent as I'd like. With that,

```
SetAttributes[sbMoment, Listable];
sbMoment[k_Integer?NonNegative, γ_?NumericQ, δ_?NumericQ, opts___] := 
         Module[{prec = Precision[{γ, δ}]},
                If[prec === ∞, prec = MachinePrecision];
                NExpectation[\[FormalX]^k, \[FormalX] \[Distributed]
                             JohnsonDistribution["SB", γ, δ, 0, 1], 
                             Method -> {"NIntegrate",
                             FilterRules[{Method -> "DoubleExponential",
                                          opts}, Options[NIntegrate]]},
                             Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts,
                                                      WorkingPrecision -> prec}, 
                                                     Options[NExpectation]]]]
```

---

### Addendum II

As it turns out, there is a formulation of the Johnson $S_B$ moments that leads to an even more efficient evaluation routine.

Draper, in [his paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/biomet/39.3-4.290), gives an equivalent, but more computationally efficient, integral formula for the moments:

$$\small \mathtt{Moment[JohnsonDistribution["SB"},\gamma,\delta,0,1\mathtt{]},k\mathtt{]}=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2}\right)}{\left(\exp\left(-\frac{t-\gamma}{\delta}\right)+1\right)^k}\;\mathrm dt$$

The good thing about this is that this is the precise sort of integral that the trapezoidal rule is very efficient at evaluating; see [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/130932132) and its references for further discussion. If speed is truly critical, one might be able to write a `Compile[]`-d function for evaluating the trapezoidal sum involved, but `NIntegrate[]` already gave results that were just as good as the results from the previous two versions, and in much less time:

```
SetAttributes[sbMoment, Listable]
sbMoment[k_Integer?NonNegative, γ_?NumericQ, δ_?NumericQ, opts___] := 
 Module[{prec = Precision[{γ, δ}]}, 
        If[prec === ∞, prec = MachinePrecision];
        NIntegrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[], t]/(Exp[(γ - t)/δ] + 1)^k, {t, -∞, ∞},
                   Method -> {"Trapezoidal", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0},
                   opts, WorkingPrecision -> prec]]
```

Comment: This must be doubtlessly accepted, although it must be called a workaround :D

Comment: Agreed, a mere workaround. Hopefully this gets noticed by the appropriate folks.

Comment: Actually (although this is not part of the question per se) it would be great if you could also indicate how to pass this to the `ParameterEstimator->"MethodOfMoments"` option of the `EstimatedDistribution`...

Comment: Ah, that looks like a harder question; nothing obvious in the docs. Consider asking it as a separate question.

Comment: OK will try to formulate. And many thanks once more, you helped me out a lot!

Comment: Did it, let's see...

Answer (score 15):

As a minor addition to J.M.'s excellent answer,

> If something breaks while evaluating `NExpectation[]` or `NProbability[]`, a number of the things that otherwise can be adjusted in `NIntegrate[]` aren't there.

Options can be passed to `NIntegrate`, for example try something like

```
Table[NExpectation[X, X \[Distributed] JohnsonDistribution["SB", γ, δ, 0, 1], 
       Method -> {"NIntegrate", Method -> "DoubleExponential"}, WorkingPrecision -> 20], 
      {γ, -10, 10}, {δ, 1, 10}]
```

also for higher moments

```
NExpectation[X^Range[0, 5], X \[Distributed] JohnsonDistribution["SB", -5, 3, 0, 1], 
     Method -> {"NIntegrate", Method -> "DoubleExponential"}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(* {1.0000000000000000000, 0.83615201160671172434, 0.70122109224906876673,
    0.58972935904106407569, 0.49730884869043345102, 0.42046180967574075322} *)
```

Comment: Good to know! Is there a way to pass this to the `ParameterEstimator -> "MethodOfMoments"` option of `EstimatedDistribution` or `FindDistributionParameters`? (I've asked this in [another question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97753/how-to-pass-a-custom-method-to-a-particular-option))

Comment: Dear ilian, would it not have been more expedient to have `NExpectation[]` inherit `NIntegrate[]`'s options? Nevertheless, thanks for pointing this syntax out.